# how to show fixed images on pageload in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page where user can select one category via dropdown list and after clicking 'go' button the relative images for that category will display on page below the dropdown list from database. This works fine. Now I want to display the images on page load for the 1st dropdown list category everytime then after based on user choice. I think my point is clear to all. for example, 1st category in the dropdown is **Featured art**, on loading the php page images related to **Featured art** always display on page. After that user can change it by changing the category from dropdown. Help me please. 
Here is my complete code :

```
 <body>
 <?php
 include ('connect-db.php');
  ?>

<form name="product" method="post" action="">
<table align="right" width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<select name="category">

 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT id, art_name FROM category;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['art_name']; ?></option>


<?php } ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input name="go" type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
 </tr>
   </table>
 </form>

 <div align="center">

  <ul class="display">
  <?php
   $id = (int)$_POST['category'];
   $sql_search = "SELECT id, categoryid, path FROM list WHERE categoryid = $id";
  $search = mysql_query($sql_search);
   if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
  ?>


  <li><a href="<?= $row['path']; ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="<?= $row['path']; ?>" border="0"></a></li>
  <?php }

  }

  else {

   }


    ?>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `GET` request instead of `POST`. Using this you may check like:

```
<?php

$get_id = $_GET['category'];
if($get_id == null){
    $get_id = <default-value-say-1>;
}
$id = (int)$get_id;

?>
```

Also, in the dropdown, set the default / first category selected.

When the user selects another option, redirect to **url?category=<selected-id>**

> This is not a copy-paste solution, please take this as a starting
>   point and follow the best-practices for development in PHP or any PHP
>   framework of your choice.

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: How it is possible to make selected the first category as the overall dropdown list is populated from database? My total code is pasted in this thread. This is a running code.

Comment: @Monomita, in the loop where you are creating the `<option>`, just set an attribute `selected="true"` for the selected id

Comment: Something similar to - `<option value="<?=$row['id']; ?>" <? = ($id == $row['id'] ? ' selected="true"' : ''); ?>><?=$row['art_name']; ?></option>`. This would mark a particular `<option>` as selected for which `$id == $row['id']`. This would work on page load and user selection change too.

Comment: Could you please paste here your code and what you are getting?

Comment: The images are changing with change in user selection. Seems as if there is some issue with the `if` condition. Please check if `$id == $row['id']` comparison is returning `true`. You may try typecasting as `(int)` for both the operands and see if this works. I think this is like comparing int and string that's why this is not working. Just check that the type of both the operands is same.

Comment: Compare `(int)$id == (int)$row['id']` and see what you get. You should get one `true` and 3 `false` every time selection changes.